# Adding an include path to the parent directory in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm wanting to include files from the parent directory in a project I am working on. All of the header files are in the parent directory, is there any way of using -I on the commandline to search for includes in the parent directory without using an absolute path?

I know I can solve these issues using a makefile and I will probably end up doing this, but I'd like to know if there is a quick commandline trick I can use as this situation pops up a lot when I am making quick prototype code.

Currently I am trying to compile using:

```
g++ -Wall -I../ simple.cpp
```

but this seems to not work properly. Will I also need to change the includes in simple.cpp from `#include include_file.hpp` to `#include ../include_file.hpp` ?

Comment: You are doing the right thing.  Why do you say it doesn't work properly?

Comment: You don't need the trailing `/`, but otherwise this should work OK: `g++ -Wall -I.. simple.cpp`

Comment: @trojanfoe, the compiler is not finding the .hpp files and give a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: The path `-I..` would be from the directory you start g++ from. Will that always be the right one? Think nested make files?

Comment: looks as though the `-I..` did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...

```
g++ -Wall -I.. simple.cpp
```

and

```
// Somewhere in simple.cpp
#include <include_file.hpp>
```

should work.