# Makefile, add headers located in parent directory (Not allowed to move inside!)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

```
dir1
--- myheader1.h
--- myheader2.h
    src
    --- prog.c
    --- makefile
```

**prog.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader1.h"
#include "myheader2.h"

int main()
{
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

**myheader1.h**

```
void func1()
{
    printf("Header1\n");
}
```

**myheader2.h**

```
void func2()
{
    printf("Header2\n");
}
```

Looking for solution on how to add a header from parent directory I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483043/adding-an-include-path-to-the-parent-directory-in-gcc) question. But it didn't work for me and I am still getting error of not finding the header file.

> No rule to make target 'myheader1.h', needed by 'prog.o'. Stop.

**makefile**

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I.. myheader1.h

prog : prog.o
     cc -o prog prog.o

prog.o : prog.c myheader1.h
     cc $(CFLAGS) prog.c
```

What am I doing incorrect? and how to add the second header without making lines go extremely long or ugly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
prog.o : prog.c myheader1.h
```

This line says `prog.o` depends on two files, `prog.c` and `myheader1.h`. `prog.c` exists, but `myheader1.h` does not (at least not in the same directory).

It should be

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -I..

prog.o : prog.c ../myheader1.h
        cc $(CFLAGS) -c prog.c
```

Note:

- `../myheader1.h` in the list of prerequisites, not `myheader1.h`
- headers should not be listed on the compiler command line at all
- `-c` doesn't really belong in `CFLAGS`

Comment: Now I am getting: `cc: error: myheader1.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: It works only if I change the `#include "myheader1"` to `"../myheader1"`. But I am not allowed to change that... I am not allowed to touch the code.

Comment: It's better to use `-iquote ..` than `-I..` for local headers.

Comment: @TonyTannous Post a [mcve]. Note that you shouldn't define functions in headers in the first place, and you keep switching between `myheader1` and `myheader1.h`.

Comment: I mean `myheader1.h`... it is a MCVE.

Comment: @TonyTannous: after applying the modifications suggested by melpomene I cannot reproduce your problem. You should probably cross-check that you really did exactly what melpomene suggests.

Comment: Indeed it worked. Thanks a lot! even though it looks contradictory to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483043/adding-an-include-path-to-the-parent-directory-in-gcc)